# Best fitting in a curve of the form $Ax^B+C$

Tags: reference-request, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

I am trying to fit data of the form $(x_i,y_i)$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, in a curve of the form $y=Ax^B+C$, where $B\in (0,1)$. All three constants $A,B,C$ are to be determined optimally (no particular norm for the moment). Also, the $x_i$'s are positive integers, if that helps.

Is there any standard method to attack such a problem?

Answer (score 3):

The standard method is least-squares, which in your case is non-linear, requiring to resort to the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm, with an extra difficulty as $B$ is constrained.

You can work out your particular case differently: see $B$ as an independent parameter. For a given value of $B$, you easily solve the linear fitting problem

$$y_i=Ax'_i+B$$ where $x'_i=x_i^B$, and compute the residual error $E(B)$.

Now you can use your preferred 1D minimizer (golden section) to find $\min_{B\in[0,1]}E(B)$.

---

Make sure to have a look at the curve of $E(B)$. Hopefully it will be unimodal (single maximum). It may turn out that the maximum lies outside the range, in which case the optimum is one of $B=0$ or $B=1$.

---

If your data set has outliers, you may need to use a robust method such as RANSAC. The latter will require to solve the exact fitting for three points.

You can eliminate $A$ and $C$ by

$$\frac{y_2-y_0}{y_1-y_0}=\frac{x_2^B-x_0^B}{x_1^B-x_0^B}=u$$ which is nonlinear in $B$, and can be solved by regula falsi or possibly Newton. From $B$, you derive $A$ and $C$ easily.

---

**Final note**:

If the dataset contains values such that $$\frac{x_2}{x_0}=\left(\frac{x_1}{x_0}\right)^2,$$ that is to say $$x_1=\sqrt{x_0x_2},$$ the previous equation simplifies to

$$\left(\frac{x_1}{x_0}\right)^B+1=u$$ which is directy solvable for $B$.

Answer (score 1):

The function to fit isn't linear. Thus, the fitting requires a non-linear regression process.

The usual processes start with an initial guess of the parameters to be adjusted. Then the fitting is carried out thanks to an iterative process.

A non-conventional method which doesn't requires initial guess and which is not iterative is shown below :

[image]

Note : For the power exponent $c$, the criteria of fitting is also the least mean squares, but related with the antiderivative of $y(x)$ instead of $y(x)$ as usual. The final regression for the parameters $a$ and $b$ is standard (least mean squares).

This method comes from : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

Some conditions about the data to a good accuracy of the fit are discussed in the referenced paper.

Comment: This is an approximation, isn't it ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust : What do you mean exactly? Any regression process leads to an approximation with respect to some criteria of proximity to the scattered data. Moreover, Yiorgos S. Smyrlis  don't specify the criteria for optimization. He wrote : " All three constants  are to be determined optimally (no particular norm for the moment)". So, the proposed method is a convenient answer strictly according to the wording of the question. Yours sincerely.

Comment: I mean, is the method bias-free ? If your data points exactly follow the exponential law, will you get the exact $c$ value ? In particular for just three points.

Comment: As it appears clearly in the referenced paper, the method is convenient for real experiments, with a nombre of measurements (certainly not three !) and scattered data. I mean, this is for practical use, not for theoretical considerations. Obviously, the result is exact in mathematical sens if the antiderivative of the function is exactly known. In practice, this isn't exactly the case since the antiderivative is numerically computed from the experimental data. In other fields of data processing, this is similar to FFT, FLT, etc. What would give FFT for example with only three measurements ?

Comment: 3 samples is for RANSAC implementation, far from a theoretical tool. Sorry that you take that for an attack.

Comment: I didn't take that for an attack. On the contrary, this gave me the opportunity to clarify some specificity of the method proposed. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Also, concerning the case of 3 samples that I called "theoretical":May be the word isn't well chosen. My comment was not to refute this case : The problem of solving a system of 3 equations with 3 unknowns can be encountered. Of course, many math-softwares can solve it. What I mean is that is a typical school problem, not a practical problem of data processing generally involving a lot of samples.

Comment: We mustn't be speaking about the same RANSAC then.

Answer (score 1):

As a "rough" approach (if I understood what you mean by *no particular norm*)
which has the practical advantage that can be computed even on a spreadsheet,
I would proceed as follows.
Given that
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 y = Ax^{\,B}  + C \\ 
 y - C = Ax^{\,B}  \\ 
 \log \left( {y - C} \right) = \log A + B\log x \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
I would :

- put some tentative value for $C$,
- perform the linear regression on the log formula, in case restricting
  the $B$ value
- look for the value of $C$ which minimize the regression error.

Clearly this implies that the least square error is taken on $log(y-C)$, that is on

$$
\left| {\,\frac{{y_i  - C}}{{y(x_i ) - C}} - 1\,} \right| = \left| {\,\frac{{y_i  - y(x_i )}}{{y(x_i ) - C}}\,} \right|
$$

The the above, on a spreadsheet Solver, traslates into:
Target Cell = Regr. Error to MIN
by changing Cell = C
subject to constraints 0 < B < 1 .

Comment: It is much better to vary $B$. This way you get a true least-squares solution and it's easy to deal with the constraint $0<B<1$.

Comment: @Yiorgos S. Smyrlis : I agree with Yves Daoust : It is easier to varie $B$ (called $c$ in my main answer). Note that, instead of to "put some tentative", the very simple and straightforward calculus shown in my answer provides a very good approximate to start the process proposed by G Cab. Of couse, this refinement can be done if the approximates already available are not enough accurate, which is rarely the case in practice.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: agree with your comment, thanks for proposing. So one may choose among a regression on $y$ if assuming that "measurement error" has a constant pdf in $\Delta y$, or on $log(y)$ if that is in $\frac{\Delta {y}}{y}$.

Comment: @JJacquelin: see my comment to *YvesDaoust*; actually, as warned by Yves,  the E(C) might not be unimodal, and thus be very sensitive to the initial choice of $C$ and this fact should always be monitored in any   non-linear regression. Does your method converge vs. an optimal $C$ ($a$), or is also subject to local minima ?

Comment: @G Cab : It should be useful to have  an example of your data in order to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: @G Cab : The method that I propose to try is very special: In fact, for some functions (such as the function considered in your question), it is possible to combine the function itself and the antiderivative of the function in order to get a linear relationship. So, the regression becomes a linear regression. There is non longer question of convergence. So, I cannot answer to your remarque, the process isn't iterative. Either it succeed at first place, or it fails. When it fails, this is due to a bad numerical integration from the raw data.