# Easy way to fit a power function $y=a+b*x^c$

Tags: functions, linear-programming

I am writing a program in C++/CLI in which I fit certain functions to some data input (certain number of $x$ and $y$ pairs). I have $7$ models from which one is $y = a*x^b$ and I have the solution for calculating both $a$ and $b$ factors (I have the sum of $ln(x)$, sum of $ln(y)$, sum of $ln(x) * ln(y)$, sum of $ln(x) * ln(x)$ and then $a$ and $b$ are just results of 2 equations).

Then I have the second model which is $y = a + b*x^c$ and I don't know how to get it. Could anyone help? I also have troubles with models $y = a + b*sinh^{-1}(x/c)$ and $y = a*x +b*sinh^{-1}(x/c)$.

Comment: Can you post your data ? is there a specified criteria for the fitting or any criteria is accepted ?

Comment: One way is to estimate the (integral) mean value of y and then a + mean value of b*x^c should equal that value. The second term is easy to calculate. This lets you estimate a, then what is left is to rewrite $y-a = b\cdot x^c$ where you can probably solve for $c , b$ with logarithms.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2025491/65203

Comment: JJacquelin the data are values from rheometer which the user put into textboxes in the program. The only criteria are the best precision and possibility to implement this in C++ preferably using just math.h library.

Comment: When you have fitted other models how have you come up with a criteria for best fit? For example in the case $y=ax^b$ if you do a linear fit on $\ln y=\ln a +b \ln x$ you get a different function than if you try to minimize the squares of the residuals.

Comment: @IanMiller
For y=ax^b I use
http://imgur.com/a/z59WK

Comment: So you are fitting the linearized data not the original data. If you've done that with all the others then that is why you are now stuck. You can not linearized the three functions you have listed.

Comment: @IanMiller so the solutions above should help me? What should I do with the sinh^(-1) functions?

Answer (score 0):

A non-conventional method which doesn't requires initial guess and which is not iterative is shown below :

[image]

This method comes from : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales